# Moving from SQL Databinding to using the Entity framework

Tags: wpf, data-binding, frameworks, entity

I'm changing my WPF application to use the Entity Framework instead of calling sql db directly.

On this one window I have a listview containing a gridview and I'm databinding it by using the following method which calls a stored procedure to get the data.

Now I already have my model generated from my existing sql database and included the stored proc...

How would I go about changing this method to read the data from the entity model instead of directly from sql?

```
public static void BindData(DataGrid grid)
    {
        SqlConnection loginCon = new SqlConnection();
        loginCon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;


        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_SELECT_CONSHEAD", loginCon))
        {
            DataSet data = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(data);
            grid.ItemsSource = data.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Function Import](http://www.cshandler.com/2011/04/calling-stored-procedure-using-adonet.html) to get the stored procedure mapped to entity in EntityFramework. Then you can directly call the function in your code with single line of code.

```
grid.ItemsSource = dbContext.GetSP_Select_Conshead();
```